# Error while parsing WSDL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, vapix

I'm working with `AXIS` camera, which supports `VAPIX API`. I need to write a script that will toggle actions in camera. For this i use provided WSDL `http://www.axis.com/vapix/ws/action1/ActionService.wsdl`. The main problem is that from time to time i can not parse this file due to error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from
>   'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/ws-addr.xsd'

This error occurs by itself, yesterday this error was gone after about an hour, but today appeared aggain in the morning. Can anyone advise anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you get temporary a connection problem to `http://www.w3.org`. Most SOAP client frameworks offer a caching option so you don't need to retrieve the schema each time. Another option would be to use a local copy of the schema file instead.